# Error sending Mail via MailKit

Tags: asp.net-core, mailkit

When I try to send an email via `MailKit` in ASP.Net Core, I get the exception:

> 5.3.4 554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied;
>   Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message
>   Cannot submit message. 16.55847:69000000,
>   17.43559:0000000060010000000000000000000000000000, 20.521

**Code send Email:**

```
 try
        {
            var fromAddress = "no-reply@domain.com";
            var fromAdressTitle = "no-reply";
            var toAddress = "mymail@outlook.com";
            var toAdressTitle = "Test sending email";
            var subject = "Hello World!";
            var bodyContent = "content message";

            var mimeMessage = new MimeMessage();
            mimeMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(fromAdressTitle, fromAddress));
            mimeMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(toAdressTitle, toAddress));
            mimeMessage.Subject = subject;
            mimeMessage.Body = new TextPart("plain")
            {
                Text = bodyContent

            };
            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {

                client.Connect("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 587,SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
                client.Authenticate("mymail@outlook.com", "mypass");
                client.Send(mimeMessage);
                Console.WriteLine("The mail has been sent successfully !!");
                Console.ReadLine();
                client.Disconnect(true);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Please help explain the reason of exception and how to fix this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the issue is? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: This problem only existed in outlook, but with Gmail it was not a problem and works correctly.

Answer (score 3):

`SendAsDeniedException` means it doesn't allow you to send an email from `domain.com`. It (the `fromAddress` field) must be `var fromAddress = "the_correct_and_real_email_address@outlook.com"`.
Here are 2 similar issues:

- [Outlook SMTPClient server error 5.3.4 5.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243237/outlook-smtpclient-server-error-5-3-4-5-2-0)
- [PHPMailer .Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40016305/phpmailer-exceptionsendasdeniedexception-mapiexceptionsendasdenied)

Comment: That's not the reason, because when i send via "smtp.gmail.com" and the same fromAddress it work fine.but when i send via smtp-mail.outlook.com this is not work.

Comment: This is the policy of Microsoft. You can't `send as` another person or domain from `outlook.com`. This is the meaning of `**Send As** Denied Exception`.

Comment: I tested it.i set `fromAddress` to real Email Address but when sending Email an exception occur: `The SMTP server has unexpectedly disconnected.`

Answer (score 0):

**First**, you don't set correct email and pass.

and you must set `Credentials` like above:

```
 var credentials = new NetworkCredential("youemail@outlook.com","yourpass");
 var client = new SmtpClient(smtpEmail.smtp)
     {
         Port = 587,
         DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
         UseDefaultCredentials = false,
         EnableSsl = true,
         Credentials = credentials
     };
```

Comment: What library did you use?

Comment: I don't use library.

Comment: Microsoft officially announced the `SmtpClient` outdated in ASP.Net Core.
[more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient?view=netframework-4.7)

Comment: yes, I know. but I still use full framework and I don't migrate to .net core.